# SwiftUI - Google AdMob interstitial not showing in onAppear

Tags: ios, swift, admob, swiftui, interstitial

I am trying to show an interstitial ad from google AdMob on appearing, but It Does not show up and it says "not ready" in the console. I have checked out many other tutorials and stack overflow pages on it but haven't found the answer. Can anyone help me? Here is my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State var interstitial: GADInterstitial!
var body: some View{
    Text("Some Text").onAppear(perform: {
        self.interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
        let req = GADRequest()
        self.interstitial.load(req)


                if self.interstitial.isReady{
                        let root = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController
                        self.interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: root!)
                    }else {
                    print("not ready")
                }



    })
}
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `GADInterstitial.load` is asynchronous operation and don't wait till ad is loaded, so you have to use delegate if you want to show add immediately after load.

Here is a possible solution

```
class MyDInterstitialDelegate: NSObject, GADInterstitialDelegate {

    func interstitialDidReceiveAd(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
        if ad.isReady{
            let root = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController
            ad.present(fromRootViewController: root!)
        } else {
            print("not ready")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var interstitial: GADInterstitial!
    private var adDelegate = MyDInterstitialDelegate()
    var body: some View{
        Text("Some Text").onAppear(perform: {
            self.interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
            self.interstitial.delegate = self.adDelegate

            let req = GADRequest()
            self.interstitial.load(req)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: This gives me two errors, one on the first line that says "Multiple inheritance from classes 'NSObject' and 'GADInterstitialDelegate'", and another on the line "self.interstitial = self.adDelegate" that says "Cannot assign value of type 'GADInterstitialDelegate' to type 'GADInterstitial'". could you help me with that?

Comment: Thank you, but now after I dismiss the ad it just pops up again, would you happen to know if there is any way to fix that?

Comment: @RyanD, well, initial code load ads in onAppear callback (which is called every time view is appeared), that's the reason. As recommended ads should be shown on some user action, so just put loading code though user workflow.

Comment: would you happen to know if it is possible to resize an interstitial ad so that it doesn't take up the entire screen?

Comment: Don't use the `interstitialDidReceiveAd` event to show the interstitial. This can cause a poor user experience. Instead, pre-load the ad before you need to show it. Then check the `isReady` method on `GADInterstitial` to find out if it is ready to be shown. See https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/interstitial?hl=en-US#some_best_practices

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments using ***interstitialDidReceiveAd*** callback for showing ad is highly discouraged by Google Admob. Instead you can notify your view that Ad is loaded and then your view should take the decision that is it the correct time to show Interstitial Ad or not. So just create a helper class with a *load* and *show* function as shown:-

```
import Foundation
import GoogleMobileAds
import UIKit
    
final class InterstitialAd : NSObject, GADInterstitialDelegate, ObservableObject {
    var interstitial: GADInterstitial? = nil
    @Published var isLoaded: Bool = false
    
    func LoadInterstitial() {
        interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: Constants.interstitialAdCode)
        let req = GADRequest()
        interstitial!.load(req)
        interstitial!.delegate = self
    }
    
    func showAd() {
        if let fullScreenAd = self.interstitial, fullScreenAd.isReady {
           let root = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController
           fullScreenAd.present(fromRootViewController: root!)
           isLoaded = false
        }
    }
    
    func interstitialDidReceiveAd(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
        isLoaded = true
    }
}
```

Now just use this class in your view and every time you call the load method it creates a new request (required as per doc). You should now observe the **isLoaded** Boolean from your View and can trigger the Ad on screen (using showAd) only when its intended to and not as soon as its loaded because we need to consider that user could be in middle of something...